# Understanding proof that subgroups of Galois group induces a simple, separable, and normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I am trying to understand this theorem from Hungerford's abstract algebra textbook.

[image]

[image]

So the part that I am not completely sure of is why $K/E$ is a separable field extension. I think the reason is because it would contradict the fact that $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$ because $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ in $E[x]$ and since $f(x)$ is also in $E[x]$ and contains $u$ as a root. This would imply that $p(x)$ also divides $f(x)$ in the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $E$. But if $p(x)$ have roots of multiplicity higher than 1, then this would not be possible.

Another question I have is why is $f(x)$ not in fact equal to the minimal polynomial $p(x)$. The reason is because $f(x)$ is simply linear factors of the possible roots of $p(x)$ that are mapped to by $H$ on $u$. However, this does not mean that those are in fact all the roots of $p(x)$. The typical example given is usually $Q(2^{1/3})/Q$. The only automorphisms of $Q(2^{1/3})/Q$ that fixes $Q$ is the identity, because the other roots of $x^3-2$ are complex numbers. So by that logic, we should have degree of $p(x)\geq f(x)$. On the other hand, since $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$, we must have the degree of $p(x)\leq f(x)$, and since they are both monic polynomials, they should be equal right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, your understanding is entirely correct. To rephrase: if an element in a field extension satisfies any separable polynomial, its minimal polynomial is a factor of a separable polynomial, hence necessarily separable as well.

To answer the second question, yes, $f$ is in fact the minimal polynomial of $u$. This is not necessary to know for the argument to work, but we may as well appreciate this fact. By construction, $f$ is monic. Let $g\in E[x]$ be any polynomial, such that $g(u)=0$. For any $\sigma\in H$, we have that $g(\sigma(u))=\sigma(g(u))=\sigma(0)=0$, since $\sigma$ is a field automorphism. Since the $H$-orbit of $u$ is precisely $\{u_1,\dotsc,u_t\}$, it follows that $u_1,\dotsc,u_t$ are all zeros of $g$, i.e. $x-u_1,\dotsc,x-u_t$ all divide $g$. Since they are coprime, it follows that $f(x)=(x-u_1)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(x-u_t)$ divides $g$. Thus, $f$ satisfies the defining properties of the minimal polynomial of $u$.

Your example is misguided, because $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Galois extension. Indeed, the fact that the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}$ does not split in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ is precisely observing that the extension is not normal.

Comment: thank you for the clear reply.  A question about your proof that f(x) is the minimal polynomial. So we still need one more step before we can conclude that is the case right? (Namely, to compare its degree with p(x) and show that they are equal). Because you have shown that every polynomial in E[x] with u as a root in fact must also have {u1,…,ut} as roots, so f divides g, but is it possible that f is still reducible? Of course, we do not expect to factor f(x) into linear terms in E[x], but it may still be possible to factorize f(x) into lower degree terms right?

Comment: Edit: I just realized we cant write f(x)=h(x)g(x) because then p(x) would have to divide either h or g, and since deg p > f, that would be a contradiction.

Comment: Could we have directly shown that f(x)=p(x) using what you wrote in the first paragraph "its minimal polynomial is a factor of a separable polynomial, hence necessarily separable as well" and using my argument that their degrees are equal so they must in fact be equal.

Comment: The property "if $g$ is a polynomial s.t. $g(u)=0$, then $p\vert g$" *uniquely* characterizes the minimal polynomial $p$ (up to multiplication with a unit, which is taken care off by assuming $g$ to be monic). Irreducibility already follows from this condition: if $p$ satisfies it and $p=qr$, then $0=p(u)=q(u)r(u)$, so WLOG $q(u)=0$ (here, it's crucial we're working in an integral domain). Then, $p\mid q$ and $q\mid p$, which forces $r$ to be a unit, so $p$ is irreducible (I use that $E[x]$ is a PID).

I do not think you've given a complete argument that $\deg(p)\ge\deg(f)$ in your post.